# Difference between NSolve and FindRoot?

Tags: equation-solving, implementation-details, system

While it is clear what `FindRoot` does (start at a point and look for local extremum using gradient), how does `NSolve` work?

Also, could anyone share a summary of all the *Mathematica* commands to solve nonlinear systems of equations?

Comment: Try searching the docs for [equation solving](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/EquationSolving.html).

Comment: I found that: "NSolve is a global equation solver" and "FindRoot is a local equation solver". Does it mean that FindRoot is satisfied as soon as it finds a solution, while NSolve keeps looking? In other words, FindRoot is an Nsolve that looks around the initial value and stops at the first solution. Correct?

Comment: Yes about `FindRoot`. I would say that `NSolve` tries to find all roots. (I say "tries" because there are computational limits.)  Originally it was primarily a polynomial equation solver, but it has expanded its bag of tricks (esp. for univariate equations).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.